# On properties of distributions in ${\scr D}'(\Omega)$

Tags: distribution-theory

For each given $u \in {\scr D}'(\Omega)$ and $f \in {\scr D}(\Omega)$:

> ${\rm supp}\ u \ \cap \ {\rm supp }\ f = \emptyset \implies u(f) =0 $

The proof uses the partition of unity. My issue is... what is there to prove? The reason probably has to deal with the fact that both ${\rm supp}\ u \ $and  $  {\rm supp}\ f$ are closed, while working with a partition (made by open sets) solves problems that can occur at the boundary of the intersection. However, since such boundary is void (as a direct consequence of the hypothesis), I don't understand the necessity of all this effort.

Comment: Can you recall what is the definition of $\operatorname{supp} u$?

Comment: $\operatorname {supp} u \equiv \{ \Omega \setminus \bigcup \limits_{i} U_i \}$, where each $U_i$ is an open set such that, for all test functions ${\displaystyle \phi_i }$ with  $\operatorname {supp} \phi_i \cap U_i \neq \emptyset $, ${\displaystyle u(\phi_i)=0}$.

Comment: I see. So for each $f$ with support in $\cup U_i$, let $\rho_i$ be the partition of unity subordinated to $U_i$, then $f = \sum \rho _i f$ and for each $i$, $u (\rho_i f)=0$. (is that the argument?)

Comment: I think you need $\operatorname{supp} \phi_i \subset U_i$.

Comment: Why? I'm just interested in the fact that $u(\phi)$ vanishes on $U$. It shouldn't matter whether or not $\phi$ is supported just on $U$.

Comment: For example, take $u = \delta_x$, then the support is $\{x\}$. Since $u(\phi) = \phi(x)$, that $\operatorname{supp} \phi \cap U_i $ is nonempty is not sufficient to implies that $\phi(x) = 0$ (let say $\Omega\setminus \{ x\} = \cup U_i$) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a class of open sets $U_\alpha$ on which $u$ vanishes, i.e.
$\langle u, \varphi \rangle = 0$ forall $\varphi\in\mathcal{D}(U_\alpha)$.

Now consider some $\varphi \in \mathcal{D}(\bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha).$ The support of $\varphi$ might cover several of the $U_\alpha$'s. It is not trivial then that $\langle u, \varphi \rangle = 0.$ Therefore $\varphi$ has to be written as a sum of several (finitely many!) $\varphi_k \in \mathcal{D}(U_{\alpha_k})$ for which $\langle u, \varphi_k \rangle = 0$ by definition:
$$
\langle u, \varphi \rangle
= \langle u, \sum_k \varphi_k \rangle
= \sum_k \langle u, \varphi_k \rangle
= \sum_k 0
= 0.
$$